# App crashes after calling AddNotificationRequest

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to test local notification on iOS but the app crashes after calling UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest

I created iOS notification manager following this guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications

Here's a code sample:

```
            var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent()
            {
                Title = title,
                Subtitle = "",
                Body = message,
                Badge = 1
            };

            UNNotificationTrigger trigger;
            if (notifyTime != null)
            {
                trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(GetNSDateComponents(notifyTime.Value), false);
            }
            else
            {
                trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(0.25, false);
            }

            var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(messageId.ToString(), content, trigger);
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) =>
            {
                if (err != null)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Failed to schedule notification: {err}");
                }
            });
```

I placed a break point to check if "err" isn't null but it's always null.

What could the problem be?

Comment: what exception causes the crash?

Comment: @Jason I couldn't catch any exception

Comment: Did you add/request notification permission?

Comment: @Ranjit yes, I did

Comment: Add try catch to the compete code which you have written in the question. If catch shows some exception message that will help you to identify the issue and fix.

Comment: @Ranjit I tried that but it didn't help

Comment: @abanoub, did you run [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications) application. Is that working fine for you?

Comment: @Ranjit yes, the sample is working fine. I applied every thing in the docs in my app but it's working only on android.

Comment: Did you implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate (sample code implementation name is iOSNotificationReceiver). If yes. Then I don't see any issue in your code. If possible share your code or project. Let me investigate more.